# Spring Boot Data JDBC: Mapping 1 to 1 relationship and persisting in kotlin

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-data-jdbc

Hello together I am currently trying to persist an entity to the database with a 1 to 1 relationship.

I am using spring version 2.5.3 (spring-boot-data-jdbc).
When I try to persist via rest post and the usual crud repository save() method with this json.

```
{
    "name": "everyday at 15",
    "announcement": {
        "name": "This is the third announcement"
    }
}
```

I get this error message:

```
2021-08-19 14:20:06.315 ERROR 7946 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.relational.core.conversion.DbActionExecutionException: Failed to execute DbAction.InsertRoot(entity=Timetable(id=null, name=everyday at 15, announcement=Announcement(id=null, name=This is the third announcement)))] with root cause

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: insert or update on table "timetable" violates foreign key constraint "fk_announcement"
  Detail: Key (announcement)=(6) is not present in table "announcement".
```

It seems like the counter for the announcement id is always going up however it never reaches the point where anything is persisted.
My entity and db setup are listed below.

```
@Table("announcement")
data class Announcement(
    @Id
    val announcement_id: Long?,
    val name: String
)
```

```
@Table("timetable")
data class Timetable(
    @Id
    var id: Long?,
    val name: String,
    val announcement: Announcement
)
```

```
CREATE TABLE announcement(
    announcement_id serial,
    name            varchar(30) not null,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

CREATE TABLE timetable(
    id              serial,
    name            varchar(30) not null,
    announcement_id serial,
    PRIMARY KEY(id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_announcement
        FOREIGN KEY (announcement_id)
            REFERENCES announcement (announcement_id)
);
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: “and the usual crud repository save() method” — can you include the relevant code, showing how you create and try to persist your Announcement and Timetable?

Comment: Maybe a missing one-to-one annotation on the timetable announcement parameter 
you had wrong mappedBy value in Image - mappedBy = "images" it should be "image":

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "...", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch= FetchType.EAGER)
   ?

Answer (score 0):

Since `Timetable` is your aggregate root, the foreign key should be placed on the `announcement` table, not on the `timetable` table.

Note that `Announcement.announcement_id` is superfluous as far as Spring Data JDBC is concerned. In the following schema I left it in but put the primary key on the new `timetable` column:

```sql
CREATE TABLE announcement(
    announcement_id serial,
    timetable biginteger, -- the correct type to use depends on the database you use.
    name            varchar(30) not null,
    PRIMARY KEY(timetable),
    CONSTRAINT fk_announcement_timetable
        FOREIGN KEY (timetable)
            REFERENCES timetable (announcement_id)
);

CREATE TABLE timetable(
    id              serial,
    name            varchar(30) not null,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```